# HTML 5 video not playing when audio play in progress

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I am working with HTML 5 audio and video playing on IOS. Right now I am able to play both. But the problem is when my audio is in progress and when I click on video to play, then it opens native video player window but within a second it is again coming back to my application. When audio is not playing then video is playing fine. I am using html audio tag .

```
            <div class= "a" id = "b" ">
                <audio src="b.mp3" id = "audio" controls > </audio>         
            </div>
```

and I have tried to pause audio in js by :

```
        audio.pause();
        audio.src = "";
        audio.hidden = true;
```

But still it is not working for me.
Can any tell me how to overcome this problem ?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/wdP5b/

Comment: how You are getting audio in js...?

Comment: please make your code to fiddle

Comment: by using getElementById . Your fiddle code is not working for me. if I detach  the audio element before playing video it is working but it is not attaching back .\